# How to remove Scrollbar from a widgets scrolling children

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ScrollBar surrounding a CupertinoPageScaffold child Widget.

Inside this contains a few horizontal scrolling ListViews which should not show scrollbars but due the parent ScrollBar being present, every scrolling widget below has a scroll bar attached to it.

Is there a Widget to wrap scrolling Widgets that removes the scrollbar?

I've looked for Widgets that may be called `NoScrollbar` but these don't exist.

If I remove the parent ScrollBar then the scrollbars are removed

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the ListViews for which you don't want scroll bars for in a `NotificationListener` in the following manner:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (_) => true,
                child: ListView(....)
           )
```

I think those ListViews will not have scrollbars.

Comment: Very smart—indeed it blocks the scroll notification from percolating up the widget tree to the scrollbar. This also works when you want scrolling views without scrollbars inside `CupertinoAlertDialog`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ScrollConfiguration** to hide the scrollbars.

```
    ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
            child: ListView(....)
       )
```

You can use this with any scrollable widget.